# How would I fit a distribution to this image noise?

Tags: image-processing, statistics

I have collected some noise data from a dimly lit CMOS image sensor.  The distribution of pixel values is tallied below:-

[image: histogram]

I'd like to be able to simulate this sensor noise.  How would I fit a statistical distribution to this bell curvish graph? And which distribution? Bear in mind that the distribution is discrete.  From the raw samples, I get mean = 18 and standard deviation = 7 (both approximations).

Comment: You can always find a distribution that fits. But you'd risk overfitting. You'd typically start with things like "I assume this is normal" or "$\chi^2$ with $M$ degrees of freedom, $M$ small.

Comment: In physics, normal is often a very reasonable assumption. In your case, I'd presume you'd see a normal distribution (representing your noise) added to another distribution (representing your signal)

Comment: @MarcusMüller But normal distributions are continuous, whilst pixel values are discrete integers. That's my problem.

Comment: So? I see how these kind of values are different, but you can simply quantize a continuous distribution or consider a discrete distribution a slightly deformed continuous one.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The only discrete one that might be the same shape is a binomial, but that doesn't seem to make sense. What might $p$ and $n$ represent?

Comment: Define a sampled normal distribution function as discrete normal. Done.

Comment: Noise in such condition is likely Poisson distributed noise (photon noise, thermal noise) + normally distributed noise (some electronics) + quantization noise.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say your distribution is discrete, if your samples are independent, you could try a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) as a model.

You can use either maximum likelihood or a Bayesian estimator.

You could also take the mean and standard deviation and use a Gaussian model with rounding. [A goodness of fit test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) would tell you how good the model is.

If your samples are independent noise generation is straightforward .  A Bayesian model is different because you use another (prior) noise generator as an input to the fixed parameter noise generator.

If your samples are correlated you can use a Gibbs sampler.

You should perform an independence test on your data, of which a Google search will provide a number of candidates

You also might consider [boot-strapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).

It is also very likely that a physics based noise model exists for your device.